# Android. how to Post Raw data using retrofit or help in using asynctask

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to send a POST RAW data of `{"userid": "userid","pass":"1222"}` as a user name and password. I have one layout consisting of username and password that will fetch as userid and password. I need help in trying this to retrofit

```
   // Triggers when LOGIN Button clicked
    public void checkLogin(View arg0) {

            // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with userid and password
            new REST().execute();

    }



    public class REST extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // The Username & Password
            final EditText usr =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            userid = (String) usr.getText().toString();
            final EditText pw =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            password = (String) pw.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
            String json = null;

            // -----------------------

            try {
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.accumulate("username", usr);
                jsonObject.accumulate("password", password);
                json = jsonObject.toString();
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mark.journeytech.com.ph/mobile_api/authentication.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String sresponse = response.getEntity().toString();
                Log.w("QueingSystem", sresponse);
                Log.w("QueingSystem", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());

            } finally {
// nothing to do here

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email + " "+ password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (result != null) {
                // do something
            } else {
                // error occured
            }
        }
```

please any help because i searched a lot and didn't reach anything

Comment: check this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Comment: using Asyntask you have done it or not?

Comment: Hi Sunil, that can be done. Pls. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428585/postman-is-working-cannot-send-raw-data-on-android/45428742?noredirect=1#comment77819608_45428742

Comment: check below answer which is marked as correct and do accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow following steps :

1. Network API interface

> ```
>  public interface NetworkAPI {
>     @GET("authentication.php")
>     @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
>     Call<JsonElement> loginRequest(@Body LoginRequest body);
> }
> ```

2. Login Request model class

> ```
> public class LoginRequest {
>     String userid;
>     String password;
>     public LoginRequest(String userid, String password) {
>         this. userid = userid;
>         this. pass = pass;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Retrofit call in your activity

> String baseUrl ="http://mark.journeytech.com.ph/mobile_api/";
>
> NetworkAPI networkAPI;

```
   public void loginRequest(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    networkAPI = retrofit.create(NetworkAPI.class);

    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(yourusername,yourpassword);

    Call<JsonElement> call = networkAPI.loginRequest(loginRequest);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
            // success response

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
           // failure response
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Dory, thank you for that wonderful comment. However when I put correct credentials like username:ssrci and password:1222. I don't get this `{
    "status": "Log in Success!",
    "ucsi_num": "MARK12302010035824",
    "client_table": "CRM_ACTIVE",
    "markutype": 3
}`

Comment: share your gradle for retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** you should create your api interface

```
      public interface Api
     {
     @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
     @FormUrlEncoded
     @POST("authentication.php")
     Call<Void> Login(@Field("[email]") String email,
                 @Field("[password]") String password);
     }
```

**Second:** In your activity you should call your function

```
    void Login(String email, final String password)
    {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://mark.journeytech.com.ph/mobile_api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Apiservice = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<Void> call = service.Login(email, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response)
        {
                if (response.isSuccess())
               {

               }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Mina, what is Apiservice and should I be deleting my Asynctask? Also, I put BASE_URL = "http://mark.journeytech.com.ph". pls. be guided. Thank.s

Comment: yes donot use your asyncTask . and the BASE_URL = 
 http://mark.journeytech.com.ph/mobile_api/         and in your api interface put your_api_name=authentication.php . i will edit my answer

Comment: Hi Mina, thank you for that comment. Btw, what's inside Apiservice?

Comment: you will create an interface and put the code inside it as described

Comment: Hi mina, can you provide complete workable solution? I am still lost in using retrofit in posting raw data.. Thanks